# What's the most suitable design pattern to implement an interface with over 1000 concrete implementations?

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns

For example, I have an interface like this...

```
public interface IInterface1
{
    bool CheckSomething(Object a, Object b);
}
```

There are potentially 1000's of distinct implementations of the CheckSomething() method, which will need to call different private methods (on the abstract base implementation) with different parameters depending on that particular implementation.

```
public abstract BaseClass1 : IInterface1
{
    public abstract CheckSomething(Object a, Object b);

    protected bool CheckA()
    {
        //Do work etc.
    }

    protected bool CheckB()
    {
        //Do work etc.
    }

    protected bool CheckC()
    {
        //Do work etc.
    }
}

//One of 1000 implementations
public class ImplementedClass1 : BaseClass1
{
    public bool CheckSomething(Object a, Object b);
    {
        return base.CheckA() && base.CheckC();
    }
}

//Two of 1000 implementations
public class ImplementedClass2 : BaseClass1
{
    public bool CheckSomething(Object a, Object b);
    {
        return base.CheckB() && !base.CheckC();
    }
}
```

I've looked at using the factory pattern, but 1000+ concrete implementations in a single class, not to mention a fairly crazy case statement doesn't seem too sensible.

What would be the most effective way of implementing this interface 1000+ times without having to create 1000+ concrete classes?

---

A more specific version of this question:

I have an externally defined interface:

```
public interface ICarChecker
{
    bool IsMatch(Car carA, Car carB);
}
```

There are numerous properties on the Car class that need to be compared (sometimes in different ways for the same property) depending on the type of car that is passed to the IsMatch method.

```
public class Car
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Colour { get; set; }
    public string Model { get; set; }
}
```

Say we have 3 car Name (assume there could be 1000+), "Saloon", "Hatchback", "Estate"... If the type that's passed in is "Saloon", we would say only want to compare the colour. However, if the type passed in was "Hatchback", we'd want to compare both the colour and an exact string match on the Model. And if it was "Estate", we'd want to compare the Colour and the Model, but perform some string operations on the Model before attempting to compare it (lets say just reverse the string for the argument).

My first thoughts were to create some kind of CarCheckerFactory, for example.:

```
public class CarCheckerFactory
{
    public ICarChecker GetCarChecker(string name)
    {
        switch (name)
            case "Saloon":
               return new SaloonCarChecker();
            case ...
    }
}

public class HatchbackCarChecker : ICarChecker
{
    IColourChecker ColourChecker = new ColourChecker();
    IModelChecker ModelChecker = new ModelChecker();

    public bool IsMatch(Car carA, Car carB);
    {
        return this.ColourChecker.IsMatch(carA, carB) && this.ModelChecker.IsMatch(carA, carB);
    }
}

public class EstateCarChecker : ICarChecker
{
    IColourChecker ColourChecker = new ColourChecker();
    IModelChecker ModelChecker = new ReverseModelChecker();

    public bool IsMatch(Car carA, Car carB);
    {
        return this.ColourChecker.IsMatch(carA, carB) && this.ModelChecker.IsMatch(carA, carB);
    }
}
```

But this would of course require creating a concrete implementation of each type to define the correct property "Checker" definitions and thus wouldn't be suitable for 1000+ variations.

So the question is how to engineer this solution in such a way as to not require 1000+ concrete implementations?

This is a coding exercise and not a real world scenario, hence the relatively vague requirements definition.

Comment: I assume you meant to make the implementation classes derive from `BaseClass1` rather than just implement `IInterface1`? And the base class's `CheckA`, etc. methods `protected` rather than `private`? Otherwise, your code makes no sense at all.

Comment: @JimMischel - correct on both counts. Apologies, I'm a little rusty!

Comment: Your question doesn't really make sense. You want to implement an interface 1000+ times.. without concrete classes? That's basically the same as "How do I run a marathon without actually expending any energy?". My advice to you is to flesh out your requirements here a little more - with an actual use case - so we can help you decide your path.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead - it's not so much about having to implement the class 1000+ times (I fundamentally don't want to do this, although it could be argued as a valid), there's just 1000+ different combinations of the way the CheckSomething method could operate based on different options and I'm looking for a better way of implementing it.

Comment: Again.. that doesn't really help us at all. Can you give us an example of what you're actually trying to do with this code? That might make more sense. Right now.. its too vague and I am doubtful anyone can answer your question. It also sounds like your interface may be too abstracted .. perhaps you would be better served narrowing its scope a little bit - but again, until we know what you're actually trying to do that's not really useful advice.

Comment: Without a little more information, it's hard to give a recommendation. At some point, you either have to implement your 1000+ different methods, or you have to define some kind of scripting language (a pseudo abstract machine code) that can define the `CheckSomething` methods in terms of base class methods.

Comment: The CheckSomething method is effectively comparing the values of two different classes, however the way that it goes about comparing those objects needs to be highly configurable and with minimal repetition of code. There could be 1000 different ways of comparing the two objects, hence the need (but not want) for 1000 distinct implementations, which is what I'm trying to avoid. Does that make any sense?

Comment: It would really be much easier to help you if you gave us real concrete information, what does it do exactly, what is the use case for it and functional goal? Replace "checksomething" by what it really does and tell us more about the project. I'm sure there are a lot much much better alternative that aren't at the class hierarchy design level, but you need to tell us more, stop trying to simplify your question because as doing so you come up with restricted options that are most likely not the best (for example, if only comparing, there are built in interfaces in .net for that you could use)

Comment: What about a single implementation with a pseudo look-up table to do the checks? You'd have a row for each "implementation" and a column for each check. In each of your examples, they'd be a single row with an "x" in the columns of the check functions that are ANDed.

Answer (score 1):

Creating 1000 concrete classes is almost certainly not the right solution. Why do you need classes to represent these different patterns? Why use *instances* of a class that implements the checker, or just use `Func<object, object, bool>`.  Keep the concerns separate.

Let's assume you have an interface `ICheckable` that has `CheckA()`, `CheckB()`, ... for the objects to be checked.

You could represent all of the different checks as instances of `Func<ICheckable, ICheckable, bool>`:

```
public static readonly Func<ICheckable, ICheckable, bool> Class1Checker 
        = (a, b) => a.CheckA() && b.CheckB();

public static readonly Func<ICheckable, ICheckable, bool> Class2Checker 
        = (a, b) => a.CheckB() && b.CheckC();
```

It's hard to give a more precise answer because the question is somewhat unclear but hopefully you understand the concept of using instances instead of 1000 concrete classes.

I'd also question why you are using `object` rather than finding a solution using generics.

Comment: There is also the possibility of composing checkers either by decorator or by a dedicated CompositeChecker class

Comment: @IanMercer - it's the pattern to create the instances of the classes that I'm looking for really!

I need to find a way to instantiate an instance of the Checker class with the correct checking options for the CheckSomething() method defined. (the Checker class being the implementation of the IInterface1 if referring back to the original question.)